# GNUplot movie from plots

Tags: gnuplot, movie

My program generates 100 plots in GNUplot. I would like to concatenate them into a short little film, where each plot is ~0.1s. How can I do this most efficiently?

The least efficient method I can imagine would be to take a screen shot of each plot, somehow put the frames together, and then crop the movie. Thoughts?

Edit: By movie I mean either an animated GIF or a .mov or something like that. The main problem is getting the images from the plots.

Comment: 100 plots in 1 movie?  It's like the opposite of Hollywood :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why use a screenshot?  Simply set the terminal to GIF or PNG or whatever, then you get the images.  Type "help set terminal" at the gnuplot prompt for a list of which terminals are available to you.

To make an animated gif, you can use Gifsicle or the Gimp.